# What will happen to data if machine having SQL Server is powered off while a long running update query is executing?

Tags: sql, sql-server

This was an interview question. Let me explain it

Let's say we have an `Update` query and it will take 30 seconds to complete but during that time machine on which we have SQL server installed, gets powered off.

What will happen to data in the following two cases?

**Case 1**: `Update` query without `Transaction`

**Case 2**: `Update` query within `Transaction`

Comment: In both cases SQL Server runs a recovery process on startup to bring each database to a consistent state, the transaction will be rolled back. Both cases are a transaction, whether explicit, or the (default) implicit.

Comment: @Stu Thank you very much, please post this as answer so I can accept it. And also please can you share some article or document related this so I can grabe detailed knowledge about it.